# Wide-character string literal in MASM?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, masm, unicode-string, widechar

You use

```
name DB "Foo",0
```

to declare `name` to be the byte-string `"Foo"`.

How do you declare it to be a word-string instead? (i.e. 16 bits per character)

#### Edit:

I'm looking for a method that works well inside macros, e.g.:

```
GenerateThunk macro Name
    .code
    &Name& proc public
        push    offset NAME
        jmp     &Name&__actual
    NAME:                               ;          I need something like this,
        &Name&_Name dw "&Name&", 0      ;     <--- but `dw' doesn't work!
    &Name& endp
endm
```

Comment: Use WSTR from here: http://www.masm32.com/

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm installing it, but shoot, did I forget to mention I need 64-bit support? X__X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with:

```
align 2
name DB "F", 0, "o", 0, "o", 0, 0, 0
```

depending on the encoding you need.

Within a macro, you may be able to automate this with the `forc` macro, something like:

```
NAME:
    &Name&_Name
        forc chr,<&Name&>
            byte chr, 0
        endm
        byte 0
```

I haven't tried this since I don't have access to MASM on my current box, so it may not work.

Comment: No, I don't think you do. :( That sometimes doesn't have the proper alignment, and it's not scalable (i.e. fails with macros).

Comment: You can get the desired alignment with an formulaic `equ` or an `align 2` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for that note, but how do you scale it though? The strings are generated with macros from identifiers...

Comment: @Mehrdad, it's a little hard to tell without seeing the macro. If you post that in the question, I can probably assist further. Or, if it's beyond me, someone else can :-)

Comment: What about `name DW 'F', 'o', 'o', 0`?

Comment: @JonathanWood:  that will work fine on little endian hardware, such as x86.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve the macro problem of how to break apart the string into individual characters.

Comment: Well, if you want 64 bit support, MASM is not the way to go.  MS really screwed up with MASM and 64 bit support.  The took away all the "good" stuff from MASM.  Instead, look into JWASM it is MASM compatible, UNICODE and 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Or use a word,...

```
name DW "F","o","o",0
```